# SQLITE3 DB data transfer from one field to another in the same table and same row

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to move data in the same row from one field to another.
This is my code, but it doesn't work with the update statement:

```
def update_ondemanddrama(Name):
    with sqlite3.connect("sky_ondemand.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "update TVshowsDrama set SecLastEp=LastEp where Name=?"
        cursor.execute(sql, Name)
        db.commit()
```

## works

```
def insert_ondemanddrama(values):
    with sqlite3.connect("sky_ondemand.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "update TVshowsDrama set Name=?, LastEp=? where Name=?"
        cursor.execute(sql,values)
        db.commit()

def insert_ondemanddoc(values):
    with sqlite3.connect("sky_ondemand.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "update TVshowsDoc set Name=?, LastEp=? where Name=?"
        cursor.execute(sql,values)
        db.commit()


Type = int(input("Doc (1) or Drama (2)"))        
Name = input("Enter name of Show")
LastEp = input("Enter Last episode aired (ex. s1e4)")


if Type == 1:
    if __name__== "__main__":
        show = (Name, LastEp, Name)
        insert_ondemanddoc(show)
elif Type == 2:
    if __name__== "__main__":
        show = (Name, LastEp, Name)
        update_ondemanddrama(Name)
        insert_ondemanddrama(show)
elif Type >=3:
    print ("Incorrect entry")
```

The error I get running this in python is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\ict\Downloads\skyondemandv1.py", line 65, in <module>
update_ondemanddrama(Name)   File "C:\Users\ict\Downloads\skyondemandv1.py", line 34, in
update_ondemanddrama cursor.execute(sql, Name) sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. 
The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cursor.execute expects an iterable. When you give it a string, execute perceives it as a 5 item iterable (5 characters).
Change the execute line to

```
cursor.execute(sql, (Name,))
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked!    Why does it work with Name in an extra set of parentheses? I still don't quite understand.

Comment: With the parentheses the parameter is the tuple (Name,) instead of the string Name. When iterating the first, you get a single string. When iterating the second, you get 5 characters.

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error, and I'm sure the basis of the the program uses the same logic.  Error message is as follows:     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    test()
      File "G:/test.py", line 33, in test
    update_temp3(value)
    NameError: global name 'value' is not defined

Comment: The code is as follows: import sqlite3

def test():
    DayID = int(input("What’s DayID?"))
    Day = input("What day is it?")
    newTemp = input("Enter temperature ")
   

    def update_temp3(value):
        with sqlite3.connect("temp.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            sql = "update the Table1 set Temp3=Temp2 where DayID=?"
            cursor.execute(sql,(value,))
            db.commit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        measure = (DayID, newTemp) 
        update_temp3(value)
        update_temp2(value)
        insert_data(measure)